# broken column mapping: OneToOne unidirectional with two join columns

Tags: hibernate, jpa, one-to-one, joincolumn

I have two given tables (posgres) with the following fields (all big ints):

Transaction:

- transactionid
- reader_id
- readertrxref
- ...

Reversal:

- reversalid
- trxref
- readerid
- ...

There is an optional 1:1 relationship between Transaction and Reversal: Transaction exists always; Reversal exists, if the transaction has been reversed. The relationship is done with a composite foreign key in reversal (reader_id, trxref). The tables are given this way and I need to map them in JPA. I need to map Reversal in Transaction that I can navigate in named queries i.e. `SELECT FROM Transaction t LEFT JOIN t.reversal rv ....`

So what I do is:

```
@Entity
@Table(
        indexes = {
                @Index(columnList = "readerTrxRef,reader_id", unique = true),
        }
)
public class Transaction
{
    static final Long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long transactionid;

    private Long reader_id;

    private Long readertrxref

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "transaction")
    private Reversal reversal;

    ...
}
```

```
@Entity
@Table(
        indexes = {
                @Index(columnList = "readerID,trxRef", unique = true),
        }
)
public class Reversal
{
    static final Long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    private Integer trxref;

    private Long readerid;

    public Integer getTrxRef()
    {
        return trxRef;
    }

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumns(
            {
                    @JoinColumn(updatable = false, insertable = false, name = "readerid", referencedColumnName = "reader_id"),
                    @JoinColumn(updatable = false, insertable = false, name = "trxref", referencedColumnName = "readertrxref"),
            }
    )
    private Transaction transaction;
```

During deployment, I get the following exception:

```
14:24:12,455 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 24) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.persistenceunit."ROOT.war#primary": org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.persistenceunit."ROOT.war#primary": javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: primary] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:179)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:121)
    at org.wildfly.security.manager.WildFlySecurityManager.doChecked(WildFlySecurityManager.java:667)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:193)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:320)
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: primary] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.persistenceException(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:954)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:882)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.hibernate5.TwoPhaseBootstrapImpl.build(TwoPhaseBootstrapImpl.java:44)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:161)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: broken column mapping for: reversal.transaction of: ch.microtronic.evending.web.model.entities.Transaction
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractPropertyMapping.initPropertyPaths(AbstractPropertyMapping.java:165)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractPropertyMapping.initIdentifierPropertyPaths(AbstractPropertyMapping.java:253)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractPropertyMapping.initPropertyPaths(AbstractPropertyMapping.java:219)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.initOrdinaryPropertyPaths(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2194)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.initPropertyPaths(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2241)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.postConstruct(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3790)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister.<init>(SingleTableEntityPersister.java:437)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor62.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.hibernate.persister.internal.PersisterFactoryImpl.createEntityPersister(PersisterFactoryImpl.java:96)
    at org.hibernate.persister.internal.PersisterFactoryImpl.createEntityPersister(PersisterFactoryImpl.java:77)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:346)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:444)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:879)
    ... 9 more
```

Can anybody point me to the fault? I just tried to remove `@JoinColumns` and to have just one `@JoinColumn`. In this case, I can deploy the application - this shows me that it is a strange error and I am not very amazed, if it is a bug in hibernate even though I thougth this is a not very exotic use case. (we use Hibernate 5.2.12 in Wildfly 10.1.0).

**Edit** Clarified that the mapping *is* transaction(reader_id, readertrxref)->reversal(readerid, trxref) and that this is given this way. I need to map it this way and I cannot use transactionid as foreign key in reversal because it does (due to technical reason) not exist in this table.

Comment: a 1-1 relation joins via the `@Id` field ONLY, and you have 1 id field. You cannot have 2 `@JoinColumn`s

Comment: I wonder where you have this info from?!

Comment: Oh, how about the JPA spec?! Or any JPA docs

Comment: OK, I edited to question to point out that the tables are given the way they are and that the mapping is really transaction(reader_id, readertrxref)->reversal(readerid, trxref). So I do have two JoinColumns. So please provide a reference from JPA docs, where is stated that we can only have a 1-1 relation on primary key and that multiple @JoinColumns are not allowed for 1-1!

Comment: I said you have 1 `@Id` column .... and CONSEQUENTLY you can only have 1 `@JoinColumn`. If you had 2 `@Id` columns then you could have 2 `@JoinColumn`. As already said ... a join is on PK FIELDS ONLY.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to solve that. As Tom and DN1 pointed out, JoinColumns must be on the PKs.
Since they are not the PKs in my use case and I cannot make them to be a composite PK (because the relation Transaction->Reversal is optional and thus, I still need a real PK i.e. transactionID), it seems not to be possible to solve this with JPA.

Answer (score 0):

Tables are joint by using the primary key. 
In your case it would be the following:

```
@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "transactionid")
private Transaction transaction;
```

The `@JoinColumns`annotation is used for composite primary keys.

I recomend reading the [wikibooks](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/OneToOne#OneToOne).

Comment: Usually, I fully agree with you. But in this case here, the tables are given and the mapping is transaction(reader_id, readertrxref)->reversal(readerid, trxref). So I have no transactionid in reversal table! (I updated the question to point that out)

Comment: It is impossible that the mapping is done with reader_id and readertrxref unless they are the primary key. But I can imaging that Reversal uses the primary key from Transaction.